# For any real number $x$, is $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ a function?

Tags: functions

I need a confirmation whether or not $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ is still regarded as a function for any real number $x$.

If I simplify the function by canceling $x-1$ in both denominator and numerator, I get $f(x)=x+1$ which has no problem at $x=1$.

According to the definition, a function maps each element of domain to exactly one element of codomain.

Comment: Your GIVEN function is indeed a function for all values for $x$ except $1$

Comment: No. Consider what happens when x = 1.

Comment: @Caddyshack: But the problem disappears after canceling the common factor of $x-1$ in both denominator and numerator. What do you think?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian You lose information upon cancelling - namely the fact that x cannot be zero.

Comment: The problem disappears *after*, but that is another function $g(x)=x+1$. The given function is *not* $x+1$, it is $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and is not defined at $1$. When you buy shelves from the store there are two types, those that are already put together and you could use right away, and those that come as a set of pieces in a box with screws and instructions enclosed, and you need to put them together in order to use them. If you put them together (without hurting your fingers)  then "the problem disappears" but before that you cannot use those shelves. There is a difference.

Comment: When you "simplify" it, you change it into something else.  The function is equal to x + 1 everywhere *except* at x = 1 where it simply does not exist.  So it is a function on R/1 or all R except 1.  The "problem" doesn't go away if you cancel the common factor.  Instead you are adding a problem in that you have changed it a lost an essential part of the function.  Namely that the function isnt defined at 1.  That *isn't* a problem.  That's an essential part of f's definition.  Getting rid of it *is* a problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common misconception that is fostered by blanket use of the term "cancelling." It is certainly true that $$f(x)=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}=(x+1)\cdot\frac{x-1}{x-1}.$$ Moreover, it is true that, for $x\ne 1,$ we have $x-1\ne 0,$ so that $\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1,$ whence $f(x)=x+1.$ However, $$f(1)=2\cdot\frac00.$$ Since $\frac00$ is undefined, then so is $f(1).$

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a function for all $x\in\mathbb{R}: x\ne 1$. However, $f(x)$ is undefined when $x=1$, as you can see. So, for any real number, in the form stated it is not a function.